# How to grep for multiple line patterns

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a text file that parses through the error log in MySQL and it looks something like this:

```
151116 14:55:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2015-11-17 14:35:48 7995 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
151117 14:36:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2015-11-17 14:36:33 12194 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
151117 16:42:05 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-22 23:17:56 12825 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160222 23:19:22 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-23 22:48:11 56950 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160223 23:08:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-23 23:16:34 4180 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160223 23:30:54 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-02-24 10:32:46 4648 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160224 10:34:24 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-03-23 16:17:10 9445 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160323 16:17:12 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-03-24 21:21:13 11696 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160324 21:25:31 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-03-24 22:23:35 22788 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160324 23:25:17 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-03-30 12:09:46 24184 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160330 12:09:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

If I wanted to grep through this breaking it down into individual groups of the following pattern:

```
2016-03-30 12:09:46 24184 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160330 12:09:48 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

So that later I can go through and grab the time and subsequently the total downtime for the instance.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: Don't use `grep`. Use `awk` or similar.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you find to find a matching line and print it together with the next one, you might use `grep -A 1 pattern`